# How to train a model given in keras.applications from scratch by randomly initialising weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

[Documentation referred.](https://keras.io/applications/)

My understanding is that keras models have weights pre-trained with imagenet dataset. For learning purposes I want to train from scratch with weights randomly initialized.

First I load the model from keras. Here I didn't include `weights='imagenet'` argument I saw in some examples. If I don't include this argument, does that mean the model weights are randomly initialized?

```
import os, sys
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras.layers import Input

from keras.optimizers import SGD

base_model = VGG16(, include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape = (224,224,3)))

base_model.summary()
plot_model(base_model, to_file=model_diagram_path, show_shapes=True)
```

Next I added back the output layers to the model. I replicated the same structure given in the original VGG16 model.

```
from keras.layers.core import Flatten
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
from keras.models import Model

# Create head part
head_model = base_model.output

head_model = Flatten(name='flatten')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(4096,activation='relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(4096,activation='relu')(head_model)
head_model = Dense(len(class_names),activation='softmax')(head_model)

# Attach head to model
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs = head_model)

model_diagram_path = 'vgg16-output-modified.png'
plot_model(model, to_file=model_diagram_path, show_shapes=True)
```

Does this approach allows me to train a model from scratch? If not what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform training from scratch you should pass `None` for the `weights` argument.

```py
base_model = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape = (224,224,3)))
```

After calling the above line you should see that the download has **not** started.

According to their [Github Source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/vgg16.py#L30) the default argument for `weights` is `'imagenet'` so skipping this argument and calling your model via

```py
base_model = VGG16(include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape = (224,224,3)))
```

will still download and load the Imagenet weights.

Comment: So, the rest of the code where I reattach the output layer is correct?

Comment: I run the experiment with `weights=`imagenet'` (updated question). But my accuracy is not improving. What do you think the reason is for this?

Comment: The rest of the code with head attachment seems ok, however I suggest to stick with the layer declaration as in the [docs example](https://keras.io/applications/) in particular + the `Fine-tune InceptionV3 on a new set of classes` section.  
About the accuracy not improving could be many reasons. Starting from the type of data and ending with wrong compilation parameters. There is too little information to guess.